# Backbone.js Models - syncing ID with the server

Tags: backbone.js

I'm having some trouble understanding model synchronization in Backbone js. When I instantiate and save a new model, it's data is sent to the back end to be persisted. However, it's unique identifier is also generate on the back-end (an auto-incrementing integer). I need this ID attribute to be immediately available on the model after the server acknowledges success. How do I go about doing this?

Just to give a little more detail, I'm creating my models like so:

```
this.collection.create(modelData, {wait: true}
```

And I would like the newly created model to have an ID attribute, the value of which was generated on the backend.

Comment: are you setting the model attribute of the collection ? more code would be nice.

Comment: What issues are you having? backbone will assign an id to a model out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Poor reading of the documentation in this case. Turns out backbone sync expects a JSON response from the server indicating extra/altered attributes you want set on the model, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the ID of the generated model back to backbone in the response.  So in your controller you can do something like:

```
def create = Action { implicit request =>
    employeeForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest,
      employee => {
        Ok(Employee.create(employee).toString())
    })
}
```

Then define the create method of your model like:

```
def create(employee: Employee): Long = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("insert into employee(first_name, last_name) values ({fname}, {lname})").on(
        'fname -> employee.fname,
        'lname -> employee.lname
      ).executeInsert()
    } match {
      case Some(long) => long
      case None => 0
   }
}
```

And in backbone.js in your view define the success callback for create like so:

```
app.employeeList.create(@model,
      wait: true

      success: _.bind((model, response)->
        @model.set("id", response)
```

You can also add some sort of error handling for a returned ID of 0.  Also, not sure what you're using for your backend but this code is for Play 2/Scala.  (And sorry for the CoffeeScript, if you need JS let me know)